# How to place the checkbox in tableview cells?

Tags: iphone

hai,I want to place the checkbox in every row of tableview.Please provide any example code for place the checkbox in tableview cells

Comment: He means that you asked 10 question and didn't accept any answer...

Comment: @venkat, [please accept good answers that helped you solve your problems](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Doing so gives a reward to those who have helped you _and_ provides a signpost to future users for which specific answer among many was most helpful in addressing a given question.

Comment: @venkat, also note ["the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) -- StackOverflow is intended to be a repository of high quality questions and answers, not a place to ask others to do your work for you. Please also read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more details on what we, as a community, like to see in questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIButton * btnShare=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270,0,32,32)];
        [btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-box-selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnShare addTarget:self  action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.accessoryView = btnShare;
        [btnShare release];         
    }    

    BOOL isShared = ([arrayOfSelectedIndex indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]] != NSNotFound);
    UIButton* btnShare1 = (UIButton*)cell.accessoryView;
    btnShare1.selected = isShared;
    [btnShare1 setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}
```

where arrayOfSelectedIndex is an array containing all the indexes which are selected.

There are few more methods aiding the multi selection of rows but I am sure the above snippet can give you some idea as to how to get check boxes in cells. [image] [image]

Hope it helps..Cheers

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [neighbourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: [[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: neighbourTableView]];
    if ( indexPath == nil )
        return;
    [arrayOfSelectedIndex removeAllObjects];
    [arrayOfSelectedIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    [self tableView:neighbourTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [arrayOfSelectedIndex removeAllObjects];
    [arrayOfSelectedIndex addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: This code is very helpfull but what we are write in selector method.

Comment: @venkat read the link suggested by Inder

Comment: @RahulSharma thanks a lot for such great effort it helped me a lot!! hey I have a small question, could you tell me what is the "neighbourTableView" I really stuck here??

Comment: Well neighbourTableView is simply the IBOutlet for the tableview we wish to shown the checkmark buttons in. IBOutlet UITableView* neighbourTableView; You can simply use tableView as its in the receiving parameter. I am also editing the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use UIButton and set it's default and selected image as unchecked and then checked.

 [Here is the tutorial](http://weheartgames.com/2009/06/simple-iphone-checkbox/),  and there are many similar questions related to this on stack,before putting same question again, try to search it.