# iOS:Adding checkmark to select particular row in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am doing project on contact list data so for that i will fetch the data and place it in the table view and i need to select the particular contact in a row and for that checkmark is applied after   selected and checkmark is removed after deselect the contact again .

```
I have searched different sites but cannot able to find the exact answer please help.
```

Comment: Kindly refer this answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3667155/3615320

Comment: Try this 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958740/how-to-place-the-checkbox-in-tableview-cells

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
 [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: i need check mark on left side of the tableview and and when i select it should be select and after selecting the same row it should remove the checkmate on the selected row

Comment: You need to customize it. You can add a `UIButton` and action to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy solution. `UITableView` manages selection of rows by itself. It also supports multiple selection. Just specify how your cell will look in selected state.

Create `UITableViewCell` subclass as code below and use it in your `UITableView`. No need to override didSelectRowAtIndexPath etc.

```
@interface CheckCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation CheckCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (self.isSelected)
       self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
       self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
@end
```